# launchctl print system printed "external activation count = 1" and "in-progress bootstraps =1"

Tags: virus, launchctl

I've been investigating an interesting user account that showed up after installing Red Giant Software called _redgiantservice. I used the following command to investigate the user id:

```
launchctl print user/1001
```

and I received the output below. I cannot find any information about the fields contained by this output in man or online. I am most concerned about the external activation count (assuming what it could mean) as well as the in progress bootstraps... I admittedly know nothing about this output though:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.1001 = {

type = user
handle = 1001
active count = 36
on-demand count = 0
service count = 35
active service count = 0
activity ratio = 0.00
creator = launchctl.7746
creator euid = 0
external activation count = 0
session = Background
security context = {
    uid = 1001
    asid = 100072
}

death port = 0x0

in-progress bootstraps = 1
pended requests = 0
pending requests = {
}
subdomains = {
}
pending attachments = {
}

environment = {
}

services = {
}

unmanaged processes = {
}

endpoints = {
}

externally-hosted endpoints = {
}

task-special ports = {
         0xbc96b 4       bootstrap  com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.1001
          0xf703 9          access  com.apple.taskgated
}

disabled services = {{}}

properties = {
    shutting down = 0
    slain = 0
    uncorked = 0
    origin resolved = 0
    deactivated = 0
    inactive = 0
    in initial on-demand = 0
    audit check done = 0
    bootcache hack = 0
    cocooning = 0
    gui = 0
    gui login = 0
    exec hack = 0
}
```

I am very grateful for any help provided!